# Notificaion.notify() cannot be resolved

Tags: android, notifications

```
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
notificationManager.notify();
```

Is there any reason why notify cannot be resolved. I am not getting any clue why it says "cannot resolve symbol notify()"

Please Help 
Thanks in advance:)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to write code in a method and not in a class body.

The first line is a variable declaration with initialization and is syntactically valid, though in an Android activity you'd be calling `getSystemService()` too early.

The second line is a regular line of code and it's not syntactically valid in a class body.